# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'link.click()') Safari

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, safari

Que tal? Estoy armando una pagina con Wordpress, donde tenes la posibilidad de, apretando un boton, se te descargue un .csv completo de todos los suscriptos a la pagina.
En Chrome, IE y Firefox, este boton funciona, pero en Safari me da este error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'link.click()')
```

El codigo donde creo que esta el error es el siguiente

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('#subscriber-download').on('click', function () {
```

Por lo que lei en otras paginas, parece que safari tiene un error de compatibilidad, o no le cae bien Jquery. Como puedo hacer para solucionar esto? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Citando al usuario iqc de SO en inglés te traduzco su respuesta

Si echa un vistazo a la especificación HTML DOM Nivel 2, la función click () solo se define para HTMLInputElement, por lo que, aunque no es muy fácil de usar, Safari no necesita implementar eso. La forma correcta de desencadenar un evento para los navegadores modernos es en los eventos DOM Nivel 3:

Adapta este ejemplo a tus necesidades

```
// Primero crea un evento
var click_ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
// inicia liza el evento
click_ev.initEvent("click", true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */);
// dispara el evento
document.getElementById("someElement").dispatchEvent(click_ev);
```